# How to add a child of a child?

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm a beginner in C# and have a simple question about TreeView.

I want to do something like this:

```
> -Root
>    -child1
>        -child2
>            -child3
>                  -....
```

I have this:

```
child.Text = des[j];
root.Nodes.Add(child);
```

But it just yields something like this:

```
> -Root
>     -child1
```

I want:

- To have a child of a child.
- To create 10 TreeNodes in a for statement.

With different names like: root1, root2, root3, etc.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the TreeNode to the Nodes collection of the child, not the root.

```
child.Text = des[j];

root.Nodes.Add(child);

TreeNode NextChild  = new TreeNode();
NextChild.Text = "something";
child.Nodes.Add(NextChild);
```

For your second Question, you would need to store those treenodes in some kind of datastructure.  If you want to name each one, a hashtable would be a good bet.

Hashtable myHT = new Hashtable();

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

{

    TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
    myHT.Add("Root" + i, root);

}
```

You would then access them like,

```
TreeNode myRoot = (TreeNode)myHT["Root1"];
```

If you are comfortable with Generics you can use the System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary instead for a generic version.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to keep track of the current node and  the child to be inserted.

- At `i = 0`, the current node value is the root node.
- At `i > 0`, the current node value is the last child node inserted.

Then, you can try something like this...

```
TreeNode current = new TreeNode(); // Root node.
current.Text = string.Format("Root");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
    child.Text = string.Format("Child: {0}", i);
    current.Nodes.Add(child);
    current = child;
}
```

The result of this code will be:

> - Root
>
>   - Child: 0
>
>     - Child: 1
>
>       - Child: 2